# Is the best way to update sections of a dynamic webpage - by rewriting the file every time?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, dynamic, view

At my company (a custom retail e-commerce website) we have a homepage with various sections on the page for promotions/sales/events. These sections may appear in any order, one after the other. The order of the sections are saved in a database table called `mainpage_sections` with an `order` column (`int`).

The present method we use for updating the homepage when the order of sections is changed, is by running a callback method that automatically *rewrites* the aspx View file itself, in HTML, with the new order of the sections. It does not pull the sections from the database and dynamically render them according to their `order`.

This struck me as being opposite to best principles and very messy. I asked why we didn't use a database read instead, but I was told that since this website is visited thousands of times a day, and the order of the sections rarely changes, it makes more sense to update the file itself, instead of running thousands of extra database reads just for people visiting the homepage of the website.

Does this approach make sense? What is the best-principle, recommended approach here? Is something like output caching a better choice?

Comment: I agree. I mean, a database query for 8 rows of data? How is that going to create a database load? I mean, all content systems pull everything from a database all day long. What do you think a wordpress site is? darn near everything is a pull from a database. But how many sections do you have? I mean a few rows pulled from the database can't possible be a noticeable load on the database - its just not going to be.  So, I would assume some kind of repeater would be used here. I mean, if it works ok now - then it not broken. But it seems less then ideal way do to this.

Answer (score 1):

Overwriting a code file does seem weird. What if you stored the ordering in a separate JSON file, and only overwrote the JSON file?

Comment: What would the benefits of that be? As opposed to doing a database read

Comment: Reading a small file would be extremely fast and lightweight compared to hitting a database.